# How to build Sherlock with gradle from command line?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle

I'm trying to build Sherlock with Gradle from command line. I'm trying to build the Sherlock library itself. Here's what I did:

1) I used `Eclipse File|Export|Create Gradle build files` and got me a build.gradle for Sherlock.

2) Now I go to `sherlock/actionbarsherlock` and do `gradle build` from command line

3) Now it starts building fine but then it gives errors **as if the Java Compiler version is 1.5**. It complains about overriding interface methods.

```
C:\sherlock\actionbarsherlock\src\com\actionbarsherlock\app\Sherlock
Fragment.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
```

I wonder why is it so?

In Android Studio it builds fine but I can't build from the command line.

Here's my `build.gradle` for Sherlock but then it's generated by Eclipse I changed nothing.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed to add it to the dependecies

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Comment: Nah, I am trying to compile the Sherlock library itself, nothing more.

Comment: still I think you need to add android-support library to the dipendency

Comment: with the latests adt put android-support-v4.jar inside the libs folder was enough an it was automatically added to the java build path.. If I ve not misunderstood your question :)